# Словарное слово "впереди"

Tags: орфография

> В учебнике третьего класса по русскому языку в словарных словах есть слово "впереди". Знакомый педагог объясняет это тем, что "о наречиях, в которых приставки пишутся слитно, ученики третьего класса ещё не имеют понятия. Поэтому словарь учебника и включает такие слова как те, написание которых нужно запомнить".

Конечно, с таким объяснением можно согласиться, но стоит ли вообще включать такие слова в список словарных слов? Ведь ребенок в первую очередь может обратить внимание на гласную и легко подберет проверочные слова (Кстати, ребенок так и поступил - нашел проверочные слова).

А вы встречались с подобными примерами? Если да, как вы объясняли детям такие места?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учителем начальных классов не была, но хорошо себе представляю ситуацию. В слове впереди 3 орфограммы, две из которых - проверяемые гласные (впереди - передний, предлог перед или переда - род. п. от сущ. перёд), но найти проверочное слово к первой гласной далеко не каждый ученик начальной школы сможет, о предлоге не подумает, а "перёд-пЕреда" редко кто употребляет, возможна ошибка "впиреди", о слитном написании Вам сказали уже.

Действительно, в начальной школе наречия даются для запоминания, потому что о такой части речи они почти ничего не знают, хорошо, если умеют видеть в тексте. Среди словарных там и вблизи, налево, направо, невзначай, вглубь в отличие от в глубь, лишь - о частицах пока не знают, рассказ - приставки раз/рас / рос/ роз (были случаи, когда ребёнок проверял рассказ - россказни и писал через О), прекрасный - пре / при, макушка, потому что "маковку" они вряд ли найдут. По-моему, это верно. Пусть запомнят, потом легче будет учить правила правописания наречий и их отличие от существительных с предлогами и другие, более сложные правила.

Comment: @ Людмила,а ученик как раз подобрал подобрал проверочные слова к первой гласной.

Comment: Значит, умный ученик, молодец, а многие затрудняются.